# How to skip a positional argument in Python Argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I use `argparse` to parse arguments for my scripts. Now I would like to write a program which runs a specific tool if the first argument (after the program name) is the name of the tool (which is closed in a class). For example if i want to run the "counter" tool I have to type:

```
python myscript.py counter filename
```

whereas if I want to run "fasta2bed" I have to type:

```
python myscript.py fasta2bed filename
```

I wrote this code but it seems like you can't skip positional arguments with Argparse:

```py
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(
    usage="""python myscript.py {toolname} filename [-option]""",
    description='''Description.''',
    epilog="""Epilog.""")
parser.add_argument('counter', nargs='?', choices=['counter'],        help='count how many features are in the input file [-l][-s]')
parser.add_argument('fasta2bed', nargs='?', choices=['fasta2bed'],    help='read sequences in FASTA format and print out BED format')
parser.add_argument('filename', help='the input file name')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--long', action='store_true', help='retrive a    long summary file (default)')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--short', action='store_true', help='retrive a    short summary file')
args=parser.parse_args()
```

The problem is that when I try to run `python myscript.py fasta2bed filename` it doesn't work because it needs `counter`.

So I try to insert all in a single argument like this:

```py
parser.add_argument('tool', nargs='?', choices=['counter', 'fasta2bed'], help='help')
```

with this aim:

```py
data = open("inputfile", "r")

if args.tool == "counter":
    counter(data).summarize()      #summarize is a function present in the counter class
elif args.tool == "fasta2bed":
    fasta2bed(data)                #fasta2bed is just a function
```

but it doesn't work because it runs `counter` instead of `fasta2bed`...

How can I make this work?

Comment: did you have a look at docopt (https://github.com/docopt/docopt) it is easier to use

Comment: I think this will be very useful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't skip an argument the way you seem to want to.  That said, it seems you don't really want to skip one.  The way to do this is change the way you're looking at the problem.  What would work is to have a single argument that accepts either 'counter' or 'fasta2bed'.  Changing the relevant lines in your code might produce something like:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(
    usage="""python myscript.py {toolname} filename [-option]""",
    description='''Description.''',
    epilog="""Epilog.""")
parser.add_argument('toolname', choices=['counter', 'fasta2bed'], help='the name of the tool to be used')
parser.add_argument('filename', help='the input file name')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--long', action='store_true',     help='retrive a long summary file (default)')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--short', action='store_true', help='retrive a short summary file')
args=parser.parse_args()
```

Hopefully this will help get you started.

**Edit for additional material:**

You can check the choices for toolname by checking args.toolname:

```
if args.toolname == 'counter':
    print 'Running counter'
else:
    print 'Running fasta2bed'
```

Note that you'll need to use [elif](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)  if you have more than 2 choices.

Comment: @chepner - Ah, yeah, copied and pasted too quickly ... Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! And how I can assign two different functions to counter e fasta2bed? I tried with an if statement but it doesen't work and always runs counter instead of fastabed :(

Comment: @Revo: You're on the correct course.  Check what I added to my answer.

Comment: Great, now it works well! The last question I have is: can I add (in this way) an help for the explanation of what counter and fasta2bed (and the other tools I will add) do?

Thank you very much GreenMatt :)

Comment: @Revo: As far as I know, there is no limit to the length of the usage message (that you defined when you instantiated the parser), or the help message for an argument.  So - although it might be long - you can use those tools to do what you want.  I have an application which has a usage message that would more than fill a 8.5" x 11" (or A4) page if a hardcopy was printed.

Comment: wow it it seems very long xD
Thank you very much, your answers helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

In a copy of your script with this line

```
parser.add_argument('tool', choices=['counter', 'fasta2bed'], help='help')
```

and

```
print(args)
```

I get the desired behavior

```
0827:~/mypy$ python stack33480471.py counter filename
Namespace(filename='filename', long=False, short=False, tool='counter')
0828:~/mypy$ python stack33480471.py fasta2bed filename
Namespace(filename='filename', long=False, short=False, tool='fasta2bed')
0828:~/mypy$ python stack33480471.py tool filename
usage: python myscript.py {toolname} filename [-option]
stack33480471.py: error: argument tool: invalid choice: 'tool' (choose from 'counter', 'fasta2bed')
```

Note that I dropped the `nargs='?'`.  Parsing is clearer and more predictable that way.  And I am just displaying the `args`.  You want a clear idea of what the resulting namespace is like before getting lost testing specific values.  What should happen if the user gives neither choice?

Someone else may suggest using subparsers.  I think that's an advanced tool that often causes more confusion.

The use of `store_true` optionals is also a good idea.  But it requires the use of '--counter' rather than 'counter'.  That's not bad, just different.

Comment: Thank you very much! And how I can assign two different functions to counter e fasta2bed? I tried with an if statement but it doesen't work and always runs counter :(

Answer (score 0):

Could it work using something like:

```
parser.add_argument('--counter', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--fasta2bed', action='store_true', default=False)
```

Also to check direct parameters after your script in python, you can use:

```
import sys

filename, methodname = sys.argv
```

now you have the first parameter you pass to your script into `methodname`

Comment: But in this second way, can I get an help page like the argparse one? Thank you very much!